# Gompertz distribution when fitting a psm model

Tags: distribution, survival-analysis, rms

I am fitting a `psm` model using Dr. Harrell's `rms` package to ultimately construct a nomogram. The package comes with a predefined list of distributions. However, the distribution that fits my data perfectly (Gompertz) is not in the list.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to make `psm` to use a custom distribution.

Thanks